# Tree plot from multiple strings, Python

Tags: python

I have a set of structured strings.  Is there a clean way to visualize this data with a tree plot?  I am currently reading into http://www.graphviz.org/ and https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydot but it seems I will have to do a lot of refactoring to get my strings into their format.

```
String                           Occurrence
A:B:C:D                          355
A:B:C:D:F                        330
A:B:C:E:H                        78
A:B:C:D:G                        37
A:B:C:E:I                        33
...                              ...
```

EDIT: Is there a way to have a tool read this ":" separated formatting of data?
[image]

Comment: The question is very unclear. Are you asking how best to visualize the strings, or how to use graphviz and pydot, or how to transform the strings into the required format? In case of the latter, what _is_ the required format?

Comment: _it seems I will have to do a lot of refactoring to get my strings into their format_ yes, when you are using your own custom data format instead of standardized formats like *.DOT, you need to write your own adapters / converters. What exactly have you expected, that there is some tool in universe which is 100% conformant with your own custom data format, and outputs data exactly as you want to? Good luck with that. [DOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)) is a standard for graph description, graphviz is one of best free tools to draw them out of DOT files. Use it

Comment: There we go.  Converting to the *.DOT format is what I was looking for.  Thank you @Rogalski. Easy how to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By transforming the ":" into "->" and wrapping with .DOT formating, plotting is easy.

```
digraph graphname {
 A -> B -> C -> D;
 A -> B -> C -> D -> F;
 A -> B -> C -> E -> H;
 A -> B -> C -> D -> G;
 A -> B -> C -> E -> I;
}
```

I tested my little snippet of code here: http://sandbox.kidstrythisathome.com/erdos/

Answer (score 1):

Not a "simple" approach, but this script will parse your file into a tree, with each "size" value stored in the None index:

**tree.txt**

```
A:B:C:D                          355
A:B:C:D:F                        330
A:B:C:E:H                        78
A:B:C:D:G                        37
A:B:C:E:I                        33
```

**tree.py**

```
import re
f = open('tree.txt', 'r')
tree = {}
for line in f:
    parts = re.split('\s+', line)
    if parts[0] and parts[1]:
        pointer = tree
        node = parts[0].split(':')
        for key in node:
            if not key in pointer:
                pointer[key] = {None: None}
            pointer = pointer[key]
        try:
            pointer[None] = int(parts[1])
        except:
            pass
print(tree)
```

`tree` will look like this:

```
{
    'A': {
        'B': {
            'C': {
                'D': {
                    'F': {None: 330},
                    'G': {None: 37}, 
                    None: 355
                },
                'E': {
                    'H': {None: 78}, 
                    'I': {None: 33}, 
                    None: None
                },
                None: None
            },
            None: None
        },
        None: None
    }
}
```